# why there is no output of following c code? is there any error of continue keyword

Tags: c

Here I have provided the C code and it is not print any thing

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(){ 
    int i=0;
    for(;;){
        if(i==10)
            continue;
        printf("%d ",++i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems odd that you want an infinite loop when `i == 10`. Did you maybe mean to use `break` instead of `continue` ?

Comment: Please describe the expected output and other expected behaviour (like finishing at some point....).

Comment: I swear I saw this same question earlier today.

Comment: this code is from NPTEL problem solving course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop executes `printf()` 10 times before it goes into an infinite busy loop when `i==10`.  stdout is line buffered by default (see stdout(3)) so it's not being flushed implicitly based on the small size.  The cleanest fix is to call `fflush()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for(int i = 0;;) {
        if(i==10) {
            fflush(stdout);
            continue;
        }
        printf("%d ",++i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You could also change the program behavior by moving the increment into the `for()` statement, and it will cause the size of the output to flush `stdout`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for(int i = 1;; i++) {
        if(i!=10)
            printf("%d ", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want to stop the loop when `i` is `10` not to have an indefinite loop

```
int main(){ 
    int i=0;
    for(;;){
        if(i==10)
            break;
        printf("%d ",++i);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
``
```

Comment: thanks for helping but this is questions about output should be 1..10 then infinite loop but output is blank so there for I can't identify the error.

Comment: this code is from nptel problem solving course